# VBA: Loop all .xlsx files in a folder and produce a list of worksheets and workbooks contained therein

Tags: object-oriented, vba, collections

I pieced together this code in answer to the following OP post on Stack Overflow: [Get worksheet Names of All .xlsx files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264698/get-the-worksheet-name-of-all-the-xlsx-workbooks-inside-a-directory)

**Task**:

The OP basically wanted to loop all .xlsx files in a folder and produce a list of worksheets and workbooks contained therein; and they gave an example output format.

**My request**:

Could I please have feedback on the following code, with particular focus on the encapsulation? How should I correctly address encapsulation so as to still produce the same output but without exposing the public fields e.g. `key`, `value`.

**My code design:**

I sought to create a process that would:

1) Get the worksheet names without opening the files;

2) Use a global collection with custom class to store the Filename and worksheet names in key, value pairs where both the "key" and the "value" could be accessed;

3) Produce output in the format the OP specified.

**Example output format given by OP**:

Number of workbooks = 3

Number of Worksheets = 100

ReportNames = TestFile1, TestFile2, TestFile3

SheetNames = TestFile1:TestSheet1, TestFile1:TestSheet2, TestFile1:TestSheet3, TestFile1:TestSheet4

**Notes**:

I didn't post my answer as I was unclear on how to alter my code properly to fix a number of my public fields breaking encapsulation i.e. I should have Get/Setters, I believe, but am not sure how to implement correctly. The overall code is a little patchwork-like and I give the links to any code sources where I have adapted code from elsewhere.

In a `class module` called `KeyValue`

```
Option Explicit
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702362/vba-collection-list-of-keys

Public key As String
Public value As String

Public Sub Init(ByVal k As String, ByVal v As String)
    key = k
    value = v
End Sub
```

In standard module 1:

```
Option Explicit

Public numWorksheets As Long
Public kv As KeyValue
Public Col As Collection
```

In standard module 2:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
    'https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/23/loop-through-all-excel-files-in-a-given-folder

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

    Dim numWorkbooks As Long
    numWorkbooks = 0
    numWorksheets = 0

    Set Col = New Collection

    'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With


NextCode:                                        'In Case of Cancel
    myPath = myPath
    If myPath = vbNullString Then GoTo ResetSettings

    myExtension = "*.xlsx*"                      'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")

    filename = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

    Do While filename <> vbNullString

        DoEvents

        numWorkbooks = numWorkbooks + 1
        AddItemsToCollection myPath, filename
        filename = Dir

    Loop

    Dim ReportNames As String
    Dim SheetNames As String
    Dim counter As Long

    ReportNames = vbNullString
    SheetNames = vbNullString

    For Each kv In Col

        If InStr(1, ReportNames, kv.key) = 0 Then
            counter = counter + 1
            ReportNames = ReportNames & kv.key & " "
        End If

        SheetNames = SheetNames & kv.key & ":" & kv.value & " "

    Next kv

    ReportNames = "ReportNames = " & Replace$(Trim$(ReportNames), " ", ",")

    SheetNames = "SheetNames = " & Replace$(Trim$(SheetNames), " ", ",")

    Debug.Print "Num of Workbooks = " & numWorkbooks, "Num of Worksheets = " & numWorksheets
    Debug.Print ReportNames
    Debug.Print SheetNames

 ResetSettings:
    'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

In standard module 3:

```
Option Explicit

''======================================================
' Required references:

'Microsoft ActiveX Data Object X.X Library
'Microsoft ADO Ext. X.X for DLL and Security

''=====================================================
Public Sub AddItemsToCollection(ByVal path As String, ByVal filename As String)
    Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim objCat As ADOX.Catalog
    Dim tbl As ADOX.Table
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim WBName As String
    Dim wsName As String

    WBName = path & filename

    'https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2cd64f27-135f-4d69-8f62-a3951c5e522b/how-to-checkinstall-jet-drivers?forum=winformsdatacontrols
    sConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                  "Data Source=" & WBName & ";" & _
                  "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

    Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
    objConn.Open sConnString
    Set objCat = New ADOX.Catalog
    Set objCat.ActiveConnection = objConn

    For Each tbl In objCat.Tables

        numWorksheets = numWorksheets + 1
        wsName = tbl.Name
        wsName = Application.Substitute(wsName, "'", vbNullString)
        wsName = Left$(wsName, InStr(1, wsName, "$", 1) - 1)

        Set kv = New KeyValue
        kv.Init filename, wsName
        Col.Add kv
        Set kv = Nothing

    Next tbl

    objConn.Close
    Set objCat = Nothing
    Set objConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've done the tough part.  You got the code running.  Now it's time to reexamine it.  How can you better encapsulate your code?  Do you really need the public fields?  Are your subroutines too long or overly complicated?  Should you move all you code into custom classes?

When encapsulation your code you need to consider more than just hiding public fields.  You need to consider the portability of the code.  Currently your code is spread across 3 public modules, 1 class module, and requires 2 external references to be set.  That is a lot of setup for 2 functions.

The 2 external references can be eliminated by employing **Late Binding**.  A common technique is to use **Early Binding** in the developmental stage.  But before you deployment you change the data types of the referenced objects to **Object** and set them using **CreateObject**.  You would then test the code, remove the external references and retest the code.  In this way, you get the both easy of development using **Early Binding** and the portability of **Late Binding**.

Developmental stage:

```
Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim objCat As ADOX.Catalog
Dim tbl As ADOX.Table
Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objCat = New ADOX.Catalog
```

Here is the same code block at deployment after Deployment after the external references have been removed:

```
Dim objConn As Object
Dim objCat As Object
Dim tbl As Object
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
```

What to do about the evils of **Public Fields**?  Pass them as a parameters.  If you have too many public fields to sanely pass as parameters, then encapsulate them in a custom class or custom type (UDT) and them pass the class or type as a parameter.

The dreaded public fields!!!

```
Public numWorksheets As Long
Public kv As KeyValue
Public Col As Collection
```

None of these are even needed.

- `numWorksheets`: Shouldn't be a public field.  Simply declare it in your main subroutine and pass it **ByRef** to `AddItemsToCollection(ByRef numWorksheets as Long)`
- kv As KeyValue: should have never been a public field.  It should be declared in both subroutines independently.
- Col As Collection: Shouldn't be a public field. Simply pass it as a parameter to `AddItemsToCollection(ByVal Col as Collection)`.  It should be noted that Objects passed **ByVal** are still referencing the original object.

### Class KeyValue

Allows you to retrieve both a keys and values from a dictionary.  I would either expand the class adding additional functionality or use a Scripting Dictionary.  You could make an argument for using built-in VBA Collections because Macs don't have Scripting Dictionaries available by default.   In that case, I would use @GSerg's answer to [VBA collection: list of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702362/vba-collection-list-of-keys) over @user895964 answer that you are using.

### Public Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

1. Changes the Application State to improve performance
2. Retrieves a folder path from a `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
3. Loops through all the files in a directory
4. Add a KeyValue class to a collection by calling `AddItemsToCollection` for each file in the directory
5. Prints the code results to the Immediate Window
6. Resets the Application State

This subroutine emcompasses 81 lines of code which take up 3 pages of the code window and perform 6 tasks.   Ideally, a subroutine should perform 1 or 2 simply tasks and take up 25-40 lines at the most.  Whenever possible I refactor any code that I have to scroll vertically or horizontally to read.

Items 1 and 6 modify the Application State to speed up the Macro.  Typically, I create a sub to do that `Sub SpeedBoost(TurnOn as Boolean)`.  This will save 4 lines of code in the in this subroutine.  By using such a descriptive name `SpeedBoost`, you could also remove 2 lines of comments.  However, you are not opening any workbooks or writing and data to the workbook, so this technique will have no effect.

Item 2 should be moved into it's own function.  This would make it easier to test and possibly modify in the future.  You should also add some conditions in case the dialog was cancelled.

```
FolderName = getFolder()
If len(FolderName) = 0 then
    Msgbox "Cancelled"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Item 3 loop through the files in a directory. This extracted to it's own function.  In this way you can easily modify and test this functionality.

```
Function getFiles(FolderName As String, Optional IncludeSubFolders as Boolean) as Collection
   'Some code
End Function
```

Main Function

```
Dim f as Object, colFiles as Collection
Set colFiles = getFiles(FolderName, False)

If colFiles.Count = 0 then
    Msgbox "No Files Found"
    Exit Sub
End If

For each f in colFiles 
    'Some code
Next
```

Item 5 printing the code results to the Immediate Window.  It would be more useful to convert convert the sub to a function that will return the results

Just a couple notes on `AddItemsToCollection`

- When passing a path As String and filename separately you should check it the path ends with a path separator.  Because their is no need to know the path I would use `FullFileName'.
- `numWorksheets = numWorksheets + 1` should be replaced with numWorksheets = objCat.Tables.Count.

Comment: Thank you for the really helpful feedback. Totally re-framed my thinking. Couple of questions: 1) Main Function code as end above.... Set colFiles = getFiles     Would this actually be Set colFiles = getFiles(FolderName ,  IncludeSubFolders )   ?  2) What kind of additionally functionality  were you implying could be added to the class KeyValue? 3) Is all the application.state code redundant in my example?  4) The function to return the output: would this return a string array for example?  Thanks again for taking time to consider my post and giving such detailed feedback.

Comment: Here is how I would design the classes: [Download Example Workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ux24lmcndnVgbFyNJqIXnw3aE8jm3ysI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You are correct about `getFiles`.  The Macro optimization isn't redundant it is not needed.  Your Macro speed isn't going to effected by the Application State because you are not writing values to a worksheet or opening any workbooks that will cause recalculations or screen updating.

Comment: If you end up writing the file information to the workbook then you should optimize the Macro speed.

Comment: Apologies for late follow-on question but I am going over my prior questions to check my learning and I am still stuck on your public fields comment. Partic the one saying kv should never have been public. Tbh I don’t have any hard and fast rule on this which is the problem. Loosely if I use a variable in many places (subs/funcs) I make it public. Problem is sometimes I do this when it is used in just two different places and sometimes more and sometimes with only 2 or 3 uses I declare locally and pass as parameters. So inconsistent and sloppy. Any guidance you could offer please?

Comment: `kv` should not be a public variable because there are not any functions that rely on the value of `kv` being modified by another function.

Comment: Public fields (variables) inside a class module are acceptable when they make since.  The main justification for using a public variable is to keep the variables value intact between for later use.  If a variable is only relevant to a procedure then it should be cleaned up by the garbage collector with that procedure.

Comment: Consider having a collection with 100 million records as a public field of a class.  When that class is no longer needed the garbage collector will clean up all the variables free up the memory used bu the collection.  Now consider that same collection as a global variable in a public class module.  When the collection is not needed that memory will only be freed by you explicitly clearing the collection.

Comment: Now consider that procedure A uses a global variable that will also be used by procedure B and C.   You just test procedure A and then write procedure B and C which both run perfectly.   Three weeks later you put the code into production and it throws an error.  Why doesn't it work now?  It worked fine when you tested it.  Chances are that it didn't work this time because procedure  B or C was dependent on the global variable being instantiated by procedure A.

Comment: Now consider 3 years done the line your need to modify a large project with many global variables.  In order to fully understand the project you will have to know how each of these variables are used in all the functions that use them.  Much better to limit the scope of the variables to the procedure that is using it.

Comment: Very helpful. So in the above I should have passed col back from AddItemsToCollection (which should have been a function?) to LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder and declared kv in both scopes?

Comment: If I only have the Collection instantiated by a single procedure I will write a `getFoo() As Collection` function.  In this way, I can easily test and step through the collection using the Immediate Window (e.g. `?getFoo().Count` , `?getFoo("Bar1")`, `?getFoo()("Bar1")`) .  If the function takes a parameter you could use ` `?getFoo(100)("Bar1")` or you make an undelcared variable in the Immediate Window and use it (e.g. `Set  col = getFoo(100) `, `?col.Count`)

Comment: Yes ,`kv` should be a declared as a local variable in both scopes.